# Updated Content to store in session storage

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to implement HTML5 contenteditable list item with session storage.

I am able edit the list item in the browser, but the changes are not getting stored in session storage.

please help me with the code below. Thanks is advance.

HTML

```
<ul contenteditable=true>
    <li>Menu 1</li>
    <li>Menu 2</li>
    <li>Menu 3</li>
    <li>Menu 4</li>
    <li>Menu 5</li>
</ul>
```

jQuery

```
$('ul').blur(function(){
    sessionStorage.getItem('loadSessionStorage', $(this).html());
});

if(sessionStorage.getItem('loadSessionStorage')){
    $('ul').html(sessionStorage.setItem('loadSessionStorage'));
}
```

Comment: Aren't you supposed to *`setItem`* item upon `blur` instead of `getItem`?

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `"setItem"` in `"blur"` function and `"getItem"` in `"if"` condition.

As mentioned in the below code.

```
$('ul').blur(function(){
    sessionStorage.setItem('loadSessionStorage', $(this).html());
});

if(sessionStorage.getItem('loadSessionStorage')){
    $('ul').html(sessionStorage.getItem('loadSessionStorage'));
}
```